# Vim and terminal in the same tab

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim

I'm not an experienced programmer but i'd like to become one, one day : )

I've seen a video in which a programmer is using a Vim session with 2 windows (and I know how to do, with `:vsplit`) and another horizontal window in which he has the terminal.

I don't know how to achieve this last horizontal window for the terminal. Can anyone here give me advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) vim plugin.

Conque is a Vim plugin which allows you to run interactive programs, such as bash on linux or powershell.exe on Windows, inside a Vim buffer. In other words it is a terminal emulator which uses a Vim buffer to display the program output.

[image]